# How to create 5 small text files from a large text files using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

Suppose I have a large file name input.txt which contains 10 lines of text:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
since the 1500s  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
scrambled it to make a type  specimen book. It has survived not only
five centuries, but also the leap into  electronic typesetting,
remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in  the 1960s with
the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,  and
more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
including  versions of Lorem Ipsum. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem
Ipsum is not simply  random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
```

I want to create 5 text files each of which contain 2 lines. Something like this:

```
./first.txt
Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever

./second.txt
since the 1500s  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
scrambled it to make a type  specimen book. It has survived not only
```

... and in continuation.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script:

```
file = open('input.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")

Lines = file.readlines()  

count = 0
i = 0
string = []
for line in Lines:
#     print(line)
    if(count == 2):
        write_file = open(str('input') + str(i) + '.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
        write_file.writelines(string)
        string = []
        i += 1
        count = 0
    else:
        string.append(line)
        count += 1
```

Comment: Answering to his own post should be to point something not trikky, hard, or specific, your problem, even if it appears hard for you at the beginning is really straight forward, and for me it didn't deserves at all a post on SO. Also there some very nicer ways to do it

Comment: Also your script write only 3 files, and misses lines. So your answer is not even correct

Answer (score 1):

A generix way would be

```
with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as fic:
    lines = fic.readlines()

# number of lines per file
split_size = 2

for idx in range(len(lines) // split_size):
    with open(f"input{idx}.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fic:
        fic.writelines(lines[idx * split_size:(idx + 1) * split_size])
```